# laravel @layouts doesnt work

Tags: layout, laravel-4

I just installed my first laravel application, I would like to create simple starter project with using layouts. I read a lot of tutorials, videos on google/youtube, I tried to coding with "copy and paste"  but in my project the copied code doesn't work.

The project was generated about description of official laravel's site (with composer).

I created a layout folder overview - and I created a file named it to: `main.blade.php` - I would like yo use this file as a layout
under views I have a folder `home/home.blade.php` - this is my content file.

In `BaseController.php` I set

```
protected $layout = 'main';//layouts.main
```

In `HomeController.php`

```
protected $layout = 'main';//layouts.main 

public function showWelcome()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}
```

`main.blade.php`:

```
html code for header

@yield('content') // content from hello.blade.php should be replaced here

html code for footer
```

`hello.blade.php`:

```
//no enter no space here
@extend('main') //@extend('layouts.main')
@section('content')

html content here

@endsection //@stop - tried with stop too
```

`route.php`:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home.hello');
});
```

On display I got only this line for result as a text:  "`@extend('main')`"

Comment: i am sorry, files names are *.blade.php, it were misspelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@extend
```

You forgot the 's', it must be `@extends`